# Jenkins pipeline get JPPF node connected

Tags: java, jenkins, jppf

I am working in a project using Jenkins and JPPF.
How do I get which node is connected to JPPF server? If possible, please give me the guideline detail.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: JPPF developer here.

You can monitor the nodes connected to a JPPF server using the [JMX-based server management APIs](https://www.jppf.org/doc/6.1/index.php?title=Server_management#Managing_the_nodes_attached_to_the_server). There are many things you can monitor, and a lot of different information you can obtain from the server and the nodes. Hopefully, the following example will give you a good starting point:

```
// connect using a JMX remote connection wrapper
try (JMXDriverConnectionWrapper serverJmx = new JMXDriverConnectionWrapper("jppf_server_host", 11111)) {
  serverJmx.connectAndWait(5_000L);
  if (serverJmx.isConnected()) {
    // get summary information on all the connected nodes
    Collection<JPPFManagementInfo> nodeInfos = serverJmx.nodesInformation();
    System.out.println("there are " + nodeInfos.size() + " connected nodes:");
    for (JPPFManagementInfo info: nodeInfos) {
      System.out.println("node uuid: " + info.getUuid() + ", host is " + info.getHost());
    }

    // get detailed information on the nodes
    // the node forwarder will send the same request to all selected nodes
    // and group the results in a map where each key is a node uuid
    JPPFNodeForwardingMBean forwarder = serverJmx.getNodeForwarder();
    Map<String, Object> responses = forwarder.systemInformation(NodeSelector.ALL_NODES);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> response: responses.entrySet()) {
      String nodeUuid = response.getKey();
      if (response.getValue() instanceof Exception) {
        System.out.println("node with uuid = " + nodeUuid + " raised an exception:");
        ((Exception) response.getValue()).printStackTrace(System.out);
      } else {
        JPPFSystemInformation systemInfo = (JPPFSystemInformation) response.getValue();
        System.out.println("system properties for node uuid " + nodeUuid + " :");
        System.out.println(systemInfo.getSystem());
      }
    }

  } else {
    System.out.println("could not connect to jppf_server_host:11111");
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that the [web](https://www.jppf.org/screenshots/gallery-images/Admin%20Console%20-%20Web/Topology.gif) and [standalone](https://www.jppf.org/screenshots/gallery-images/Admin%20Console%20-%20Desktop/Topology-TreeView.gif) administration consoles, which are built on top of the same management APIs, will also provide this information.

Comment: Hi Lolo, Thank you very much for your help. I have got the way to monitor the nodes connected by using JMXDriverConnectionWrapper.

Comment: Also, could you help me this: I wanna get the computer name ( not getHost() because it will return the full computer name). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hùng-nguyễn I do not uunderstand what you're asking. Could you provide an example of what you're looking for and how the value returned by `getHost()` does not provide it?

Comment: I have got the what i need. But now i need others. How do i get the nodes which is executed the task? 
For exp: I submit 80 tasks, but there are 100 nodes in my system. I just want to collect results in that's 80 nodes which executed the task. 
Thank in advance